# My question edit is only displayed correctly in revisions, but not on main site

Tags: bug, edits, revisions-list, editor

I edited the question https://askubuntu.com/q/877978/367990 (now deleted unfortunately) to correct the formatting.

When you follow the link and look at the site, it looks like this:

[image: main site view]

You see that the question is not properly formatted, my edit was not applied. However, I am shown as the last editor.

Clicking on the revisions link, there are two revisions, the original post and my edit. Strangely, my edit is displayed there correctly:

[image: revisions view]

Also when I click the edit button again, my modified version is shown in the editor and preview, just like if my edit had been applied successfully.

[image: editor view]

This is likely not a caching or client-side issue, as I get the same look from different browsers, logged in or out. Another user (@terdon, Ask Ubuntu moderator) [also confirmed he sees what I describe in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35101417#35101417). Anyway, my browsers were Firefox 52 and MS Edge on Windows 10.

I guess that something got confused because two edits (mine and someone else's, probably the OP's) got submitted in the same second...

What exactly happened here and can it please be fixed? Thanks.

Comment: The question was deleted by its author, so most people won't see anything.

Comment: Oh, I see this just happened. Fortunately I made screenshots.

Comment: It might be local on AskUbuntu because your markdown seemed correct on that revision and I tried it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/269494#269494) but no-repro ... so ... we wait for a dev.